# Python and PDF Forms - error with field name

Tags: python, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I'm using this Python code to get info from a PDF form (field names and field contents):

```
import sys
import six
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdftypes import resolve1

fp = open("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Example.pdf", "rb")

parser = PDFParser(fp)
doc = PDFDocument(parser)
fields = resolve1(doc.catalog["AcroForm"])["Fields"]
for i in fields:
    field = resolve1(i)
    name, value = field.get("T"), field.get("V")
    print ("{0}:{1}".format(name,value))
```

It works fine, but my problem is related to the field names. I need this names to be exactly like my db, respecting this: LL.LL.NNNN (L-Letter, N-Number).

When I rename the fields names with this nomenclature, the code doesn't work as expected. First, I thought this was a problem related do Adobe Acrobat Pro DC. But I did the renaming using PDFStudio too and the same error occours. This is what I get from Python debug console:

```
NORMAL NAMING

1. b'Given Name Text Box':b'John'
2. b'Family Name Text Box':b'Smith'
3. b'House nr Text Box':b'32'
4. b'Address 2 Text Box':b'45 Street'
5. b'Postcode Text Box':b'12345'
6 b'Country Combo Box':b'Portugal'
7. b'Height Formatted Field':b'190'
8. b'City Text Box':b'Lisbon'
9. b'Driving License Check Box':/'Yes'
10. b'Favourite Colour List Box':b'Yellow'
11. b'Language 1 Check Box':/'Off'
12. b'Language 2 Check Box':/'Yes'
13. b'Language 3 Check Box':/'Off'
14. b'Language 4 Check Box':/'Off'
15. b'Language 5 Check Box':/'Yes'
16. b'Gender List Box':b'\xfe\xff\x00M\x00a\x00n'
17. b'Address 1 Text Box':b'44 Street'
```

```
WITH MY NOMENCLATURE NAMING

1. b'Family Name Text Box':b'Smith'
2. b'House nr Text Box':b'32'
3. b'Address 2 Text Box':b'45 Street'
4. b'Postcode Text Box':b'12345'
5. b'Country Combo Box':b'Portugal'
6. b'Height Formatted Field':b'190'
7. b'City Text Box':b'Lisbon'
8. b'Driving License Check Box':/'Yes'
9. b'Favourite Colour List Box':b'Yellow'
10. b'Language 1 Check Box':/'Off'
11. b'Language 2 Check Box':/'Yes'
12. b'Language 3 Check Box':/'Off'
13. b'Language 4 Check Box':/'Off'
14. b'Language 5 Check Box':/'Yes'
15. b'Gender List Box':b'\xfe\xff\x00M\x00a\x00n'
16. b'Address 1 Text Box':b'44 Street'
17. b'MD':None
```

I have changed the name of the first field from "Given Name Text Box" to "MD.LE.0001". Python result only reads "MD", shows the field content as "none" and changed the order of the fields, sending the renamed field from line 1 to line 17.

I wanna know what's happening and what are the "b" letters that Python presents in the result.

[Link for the pdf file used in this test](https://campustecnologicoalgeciras.es/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/OoPdfFormExample.pdf)

Comment: Period characters are forbidden in the **T** value, the *partial field name*, cf. ISO 32000-1 section 12.7.3.2 Field Names, they are reserved for building fully qualified names from these partial field names.

Answer (score 0):

If you parse the PDF file (instead of actually rendering it), you have to be aware that the field names will be hierarchic, meaning that you have the first group (in the example `MD`), and then a kid named `LE` which itself has a kid named `0001`. If there are kids, it is indicated in the field description.

So, if you encounter the "have kids" indicator, you would have to find those kids and assemble the field name accordingly.